# Error while storing bytes in database ,Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

```
public void InsertMails(string From, string To, string Date, string Content, string AttachmentPath, byte[] CCD)
{
   ClassLibrary.ConnectionClass.CurrentConnection.ExecuteNonReader("Insert into RecieveDirectMails([From],[To],Date,[Content],AttachmentPath,CreationDate,LastUpdatedDate,IsReviewed,LastUpdatedBy,IsDeleted,IsLocked,LockedBy,CCD) values ('" + From + "','" + To + "','" + Date + "','" + Content + "','" + AttachmentPath + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + "0" + "','" + "0" + "','" + "0" + "','" + "0" + "','" + "0" + "','" + CCD+ "')");
}
```

I am storing XML file bytes into Database but the error occurred.

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Where I am doing it wrong can any one help me out .

In the database the `CCD` column is of datatype `varbinary(MAX)`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: database is SQLSERVER .

Comment: Simple question is that why i am facing this error "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: Well, your column is a `VARBINARY` so it expects **binary data** as the name implies - but your last values provided is in double quotes ( `"........"` ) so therefore it's **a string** and those cannot be converted automatically. Either you have the wrong datatype and it really should be a string format (e.g. `VARCHAR(MAX)`), or then you need to provide the data **as a binary blob of data** and not as a string in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: Yeah i think you are right , let me try it once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary values in T-SQL are represented by hexadecimal-encoded literals prefixed with `0x`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Foo ( Col ) VALUES ( 0xDEADBEEF )
```

However if you're doing it from code please use parameterised queries with `SqlParameter` to avoid injection attacks:

```
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Foo ( Col ) VALUES ( @col )";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@col", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = new Byte[] { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF };
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is this possible to do as the same way as i posted a question ?
means I wanted to simply store my Bytes into Database